# Script works fine but doesnot execute delays

Tags: php

I made an upload script where user uploads a file after the upload user get redirected to next page where i dump that file to database and show a gif image of `loading data..` and then put `sleep(10)` to create delay and replace that image with `showing data`. Problem 
I am facing is that after upload the code takes `sleep(10)` as execution time and display the final output on the next page no matter how many delays are being passed in that file and all those delays adds up to the execution time and shows the user final output after the dump is being done. Kindly let me know why is this happening.

Note I used flush () it didnot work either and its enabled in my config file

```
<?php 
flush();
ob_flush();
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="<img src='."images/L.gif".' />"</script>';
sleep(30);
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="<img src='."images/C.gif".' />"</script>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are solutions to this (namely to `flush` after your `echo` statement and before your `sleep` statement). But, this isn't likely to do what you want cross-browser anyway. AJAX would be a much better solution for this sort of task (most likely).

Depending on the browser and configuration, the browser may not start rendering anything until the connection to your server is closed. In this case, the user will see nothing on their screen until all of your delays have passed.

Comment: hmmm okay I guess only way to make it work is to trigger  ajax call cause flush trick is not working....

Answer (score 2):

You are flusing output and them add an string to buffer then sleep and again add another string to buffer then flush again.
Use `ob_flush()` after first echo before the sleep;

```
ob_start();
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="<img src='."images/L.gif".' />"</script>';
ob_flush();
sleep(30);
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="<img src='."images/C.gif".' />"</script>';
```

You can turn off `output_buffering` too.

**And use AJAX with fixed delay checks instead of using an endless load of page.**

Comment: +1 , I guess i was using wrong approach from the beginning i should have done it via ajax cause my time got wasted alot in order to make it work on php (which i could not)... I am switching to ajax now and it works as its client side doesn't bother what going on server side :)